# Para que criar um método construtor, se o mesmo já é criado automaticamente em C#?

Tags: c#

Recentemente me deparei com a pergunta "Qual a necessidade de se criar um método construtor?", e sinceramente, como o mesmo é criado de forma automática quando é feita a classe, para que criá-lo, então?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73530/para-que-serve-um-construtor#:~:text=O%20construtor%20tamb%C3%A9m%20permite%20determinar,porque%20pode%20n%C3%A3o%20ser%20determin%C3%ADstico.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73530/para-que-serve-um-construtor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os métodos construtores server para esse príncípio: "Construir" ou melhor inicializar a classe, para que seja possível instancia-la de 'n' formas.

Temos casos em que precisamos iniciar a mesma classe com valores iniciais diferentes, por ex:

```
namespace Teste
{
    public class Pessoa
    {
        public Pessoa(string nome, string documento, int idade)
        {
            Nome = nome;
            Documento = documento;
            Idade = idade;
        }

        public Pessoa(string nome, string documento)
        {
            Nome = nome;
            Documento = documento;
        }

        public Pessoa(string nome, int idade)
        {
            Nome = nome;
            Idade = idade;
        }

        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Documento { get; set; }
        public int Idade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Podemos incializar essa mesma classe de diversas formas, à partir dos nossos construtores.

```
namespace Teste
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var joao = new Pessoa("João", 15);
            var pedro = new Pessoa("Pedro", "111.111.111-11");
            var maria = new Pessoa("Maria", "222.222.222-22", 15);
        }
    }
}
```

Se você não definir nenhum método construtor na sua classe, sua classe será inicializada com todos os atributos default(string = null,int = 0)